# mahout ssvd job performance

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I need to compute ssvd.
For 50 000 x 50 000 matrix, when reducing to 300x300 libraries such as ssvdlibc and other can compute it in less than 3 minutes;

I wanted to do it for big data, tried using mahout. Firstly I tried to run it locally on my small data set (that is 50000 x 50000), but it takes 32 minutes to complete that simple job, uses around 5,5GB of disk space for spill files, cause my intel i5 with 8GiB ram and SSD drive to freeze for few times.

I understand that mahout and hadoop must do lots of additional steps to perform everything as map-reduce job, but the performance hit just seems to big. I think I must have something wrong in my setup.

I've read some hadoop and mahout documentation, added few parameters in my config files, but its still incredibly slow. Most of time it uses only one CPU.

Can someone please tell me is what is wrong with my setup ? Can It be somehow tuned for that simple, one mahine use just to see what to look for for bigger deployment ?

my config files :
mapred-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>local</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
 <value>-Xmx5000M</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
 <value>3</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
 <value>3</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>io.sort.factor</name>
<value>35</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>file:///</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>file:///</value>
</property>



<!--
<property>
 <name>fs.inmemory.size.mb</name>
 <value>200</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>io.sort.factor</name>
 <value>100</value>
</property>
-->
<property>
 <name>io.sort.mb</name>
 <value>200</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>io.file.buffer.size</name>
 <value>131072</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

I run my job like that:

```
mahout ssvd --rank 400 --computeU true --computeV true --reduceTasks 3  --input ${INPUT} --output ${OUTPUT} -ow --tempDir /tmp/ssvdtmp/
```

I also configured hadoop to and mahout with -Xmx=4000m

Answer (score 1):

Well so first of all I would verify that it is running in parallel, make sure hdfs replication is set to "1", and just generally check your params.  That only seeing one core be used is definitely an issue!

But!

The problem with slowness is probably not going to go away completely, you might be able to speed it up significantly with proper configuration, but at the end of the day the hadoop model is not going to outcompete optimized shared memory model libraries on a single computer.

The power of hadoop/mahout is for big data, and honestly 50k x 50k is still in the realm of fairly small, easily manageable on a single computer.  Essentially, Hadoop trades speed for scalability. So while it might not outcompete those other two with 50000 x 50000, try to get them to work on 300000 x 300000 while with Hadoop you are sitting pretty on a distributed cluster.

Comment: I've got hdfs replication set to 1. I've changed my jobtracker from local to:
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:54311</value> now my mapred.map.tasks property takes effect. now in works on one or two of four cores - little bit better but stil poor, execution time is around 5 mins better

Comment: Bt-job is one responsible for creating huge spills. I'll try to modify io.sort.mb  to some big value, like 5000 and see if that helps

Comment: I wish hadoop had some automatic utilitiy to change selected configuration variables across a specified range and run speed tests.  It would be very useful in making the cluster work well